# Is there a decent way to maintain development of wordpress sites using the same base?

Tags: git, wordpress

We've been churning out wordpress sites for a while, and we'd like to keep a base repository that can be used when starting a new project, as well as updating existing sites with changes to the wordpress base.

Am I wrong in assuming this would be a good thing? We take care of updating the sites, so having a common base would make this easier.

I've been looking at solutions using git, such as forking a base repository and using it to pull changes to the wordpress base, but committing the site to it's own repository. Or maybe, if it's possible, storing the base as a git submodule, but this would require storing themes and plugins outside of that.

Is there any common way to go about this kind of website development?

Comment: You may also want to check out the WordPress StackExchange site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=git

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not wrong in assuming it is a good thing; it makes a lot of sense if your business is spinning up WordPress sites for clients, and those base installations include your company's own set of custom themes, plugins, or other modifications to the *actual* WordPress base.

[Mark Jaquith](http://markjaquith.com/), lead WordPress dev, does something along those lines himself, with his [WordPress-Skeleton](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton) repo on GitHub, where he says to feel free to "use it to jump-start your WordPress site repos, or fork it and customize it to your own liking!"

Answer (score 1):

I am not the author of this article, and it uses Subversion as its repository, but there are good things that help to combine WordPress and version control in its content:

[Creating a WordPress Site Using SVN](http://ottopress.com/2011/creating-a-wordpress-site-using-svn/)